# RestKit send post request, parse the result?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, post, restkit

I'm trying to pull data from my web service API and parse the received JSON... I've been though RestKit tutorials, but I couldn't find any information on doing a post request!

Right now I have this code:

```
-(void) loadPerformers
{
// Create our request mapping
RKObjectMapping* requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[JsonOperationModel class]];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"RequestType"]];

// Create our data mapping
RKObjectMapping* dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DataModel class] ];
[dataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"Status"]];

// Create our performer mapping
RKObjectMapping* performerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PerformerModel class] ];
[performerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"IdPerformer", @"Name", @"Rate",
                                                  @"IsInWatch", @"Rating", @"PictureUrl", @"LastModifiedDate"]];

// Create our talent mapping
RKObjectMapping* talentMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DataModel class] ];
[talentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"Id", @"Value"]];

// Define the relationship mapping with request -> data
[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"data"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"data"
                                                                             withMapping:dataMapping]];
// Define the relationship mapping with data -> performers
[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Performers"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"Performers"
                                                                             withMapping:performerMapping]];
// Define the relationship mapping with performer -> talent
[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Talents"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"Talents"
                                                                             withMapping:talentMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:JsonOperationMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.10.5.106:8089/Mobile/Default.ashx"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor]];
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    RKLogInfo(@"result: %@", mappingResult.array);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];

[objectRequestOperation start];
}
```

Which was a sample on an official tutorial of RestKit, modified to my needs according to my json. But how can I adapt this sample to send a JSON string to the URL, and then fetch the server anwser?

I couldn't find any information on that, and each of my server response needs some client information sent through a JSON string before being able to send a response back to the client. (It's isn't only fetching from an URL as my current sample does!)

Thanks for any input on this!

Comment: You would usually use an `RKObjectManager` (check the docs for this) and you need a request descriptor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've just looked into that class and I think I found something interesting under "Request and Response Descriptors" ! I think I'm on the right way.